# How to Calculate Days,Weeks,Month,Year difference from Today's Date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-difference

I need to check one process occurred how many times in the selected time period. My time period saved as in Days,Months,Weeks or Year format. Example: 3 Years or 4 Weeks or 2 months or 5 days.. something like this.

How to calculate 4 weeks or 3 years or 2 months or 5 days from today's date?

```
Which means : Today is 23 May 2022  
>> 4 Weeks past of today is 22 April 2022
>> 3 Years past of today is 23 May 2019
>> 2 Months past of today is 23 March 2022
>> 5 Days past of today is 18 May 2019
```

How to calculate this in procedure to check my condition?

I got no idea in this ,as I am new to stored procedure.

Referred many similar questions, found out need to use DATEDIFF , but dont know how to use for my requirement.

Kindly help

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own functions.)

Comment: we r using SQL Server

Comment: you need to use dateadd not datediff https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7063259/regbes used dateadd.. got expected result..thank u

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this query can give you clue how to calculate date

```
select
'today is '+convert(varchar,getdate(),106),
'4 weeks past of today is '+convert(varchar,DATEADD(WEEK,-4,getdate()),106),
'3 years past of today is '+convert(varchar,DATEADD(YEAR,-3,getdate()),106),
'2 months past of today is '+convert(varchar,DATEADD(MONTH,-2,getdate()),106),
'5 days past of today is '+convert(varchar,DATEADD(DAY,-5,getdate()),106)
```

hope this can help you